# Python - find N maximum number in a list of lists with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, max

I have a list of lists

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.array([[1, 9, 4,4, 5,4, 6, 13, 22, 3, 5, 2, 55, 6, 18],
                   [12, 44, 3, 6],
                   [22, 3, 12,44, 65, 8],
                   [144, 15, 13, 12, 1, 9, 44, 67, 187, 2, 6, 17, 66, 88, 99]])
```

I want to find the index of top 10 max, and top 10 max number in each list. How can I do it? Is there a function in numpy or pandas for it?

```
top10_index = 
top10_max =
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in pure python this way

```
import heapq

mylist = [[1, 9, 4,4, 5,4, 6, 13, 22, 3, 5, 2, 55, 6, 18],
                   [12, 44, 3, 6],
                   [22, 3, 12,44, 65, 8],
                   [144, 15, 13, 12, 1, 9, 44, 67, 187, 2, 6, 17, 66, 88, 99]]
print([heapq.nlargest(10, L) for L in mylist])
# [[55, 22, 18, 13, 9, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4], [44, 12, 6, 3], [65, 44, 22, 12, 8, 3], [187, 144, 99, 88, 67, 66, 44, 17, 15, 13]]
print([heapq.nlargest(10, range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__) for L in mylist])
# [[12, 8, 14, 7, 1, 6, 13, 4, 10, 2], [1, 0, 3, 2], [4, 3, 0, 2, 5, 1], [8, 0, 14, 13, 7, 12, 6, 11, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas you can create `DataFrame` with list comprehension for tuples:

```
L = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(mylist) for y in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['no','val'])
```

Then if need order of original create new column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby('no').cumcount()
```

Then sorting:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['no','val'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df1)
    no  val  counter
12   0   55       12
8    0   22        8
14   0   18       14
7    0   13        7
1    0    9        1
6    0    6        6
13   0    6       13
4    0    5        4
10   0    5       10
2    0    4        2
3    0    4        3
5    0    4        5
9    0    3        9
11   0    2       11
0    0    1        0
16   1   44        1
15   1   12        0
18   1    6        3
17   1    3        2
23   2   65        4
22   2   44        3
19   2   22        0
21   2   12        2
24   2    8        5
20   2    3        1
33   3  187        8
25   3  144        0
39   3   99       14
38   3   88       13
32   3   67        7
37   3   66       12
31   3   44        6
36   3   17       11
26   3   15        1
27   3   13        2
28   3   12        3
30   3    9        5
35   3    6       10
34   3    2        9
29   3    1        4
```

And last create top values with filter by [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html) and convert to lists in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
N = 3
top10_index = df1.groupby('no')['counter'].agg(lambda x: x.head(N).tolist()).tolist()
print (top10_index)
[[12, 8, 14], [1, 0, 3], [4, 3, 0], [8, 0, 14]]

top10_max = df1.groupby('no')['val'].agg(lambda x: x.head(N).tolist()).tolist()
print (top10_max)
[[55, 22, 18], [44, 12, 6], [65, 44, 22], [187, 144, 99]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, The result is great! I would like to ask how can I arrange the result as list of lists? like in mylist data?

Answer (score 0):

The list was added to the DF from the loop and then calculated.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['list_no', 'idx', 'value'])
for i,lst in enumerate(mylist):
    for k, val in enumerate(lst):
        tmp = pd.Series([i, k, val], index=data.columns, name=k)
        data = data.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)

data.sort_values('value', ascending=False, inplace=True)
top10_max = data['value'].head(10)
top10_index = list(zip(data['list_no'], data['idx']))[0:10]
```